# MySQL, Join two rows from one table and ignore doublons

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table "user" like this :

```
| uid | username |
|  1  | Jack     |
|  2  | John     |
|  3  | Robert   |
```

Using my request :

```
SELECT u1.username, u2.username FROM user u1 JOIN user u2
```

Using this request, I get a table like this :

```
| uid | username | uid | username |
|  1  | Jack     |  1  | Jack     |
|  1  | Jack     |  2  | John     |
|  1  | Jack     |  3  | Robert   |
|  2  | John     |  1  | Jack     |
|  2  | John     |  2  | John     |
|  2  | John     |  3  | Robert   |
|  3  | Robert   |  1  | Jack     |
|  3  | Robert   |  2  | John     |
|  3  | Robert   |  3  | Robert   |
```

How can I remove one of these duets?

```
|  1  | Jack     |  2  | John     |
|  2  | John     |  1  | Jack     |
```

Comment: So your goal is to get a list pairing every user once with every other user?

Comment: All of them are paired, so essentially you want to select nothing?

Comment: If I understand, your ultimate result would be only 3 rows: `(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)`, unless you also wanted to keep `(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)`

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.
(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,2)(2,3)(3,3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want all combinations of User table 1 with User table 2. I believe this would accomplish this:

```
SELECT u1.id, u1.name, u2.id u2.name
FROM User u1
INNER JOIN User u2
WHERE u1.id >= u2.id
```

This would give the following result:

```
| uid | username | uid | username |
|  1  | Jack     |  1  | Jack     |
|  2  | John     |  1  | Jack     |
|  2  | John     |  2  | John     |
|  3  | Robert   |  1  | Jack     |
|  3  | Robert   |  2  | John     |
|  3  | Robert   |  3  | Robert   |
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. How easy it is, and I didn't think about it. :-)